Refresh page its not working and renders my component with user: null
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as coreApi from '@services/ohtCore/Endpoint.ts';
import { Permissions, User } from '@services/ohtCore/types.ts';
import {
  clearAuthTokens,
  getAuthTokens,
  setAuthTokensInCookies,
} from '@services/auth/tokenStorage.ts';
import logger from '@utils/logger.ts';
import LoadingSpinner from '@components/LoadingSpinner';

interface AuthContextProps {
  user: User | null;
  accessToken: string | null;
  login: (username: string, password: string) => any;
  logout: () => any;
  isPermissionPresent: (permission: Permissions) => any;
  refreshExpiredToken: () => any;
  checkForImpersonationToken: () => any;
  fetchUser: () => Promise<User | null>;
}

const defaultAuthContext: AuthContextProps = {
  user: null,
  accessToken: null,
  login: async () => {},
  logout: () => {},
  isPermissionPresent: () => {},
  refreshExpiredToken: () => {},
  checkForImpersonationToken: async () => {},
  fetchUser: async () => null,
};

const AuthContext = createContext(defaultAuthContext);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Retrieve the existing token from cookies on page load
    console.log('User:', user);
  }, [user]);

  const checkForImpersonationToken = async () => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const impersonationToken = urlParams.get('imp');

    if (impersonationToken) {
      try {
        // Remove the impersonation token from the URL after using it
        window.history.replaceState(
          {},
          document.title,
          window.location.pathname
        );
        const response = await coreApi.RefreshTokens.post({
          refreshToken: impersonationToken,
        });
        const { token, refreshToken, expiresAt } = response;

        // Set token in cookies
        setAuthTokensInCookies({ token, refreshToken, expiresAt });
        setAccessToken(token);
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Failed to impersonate user', error);
        setAccessToken(null);
      }
    } else {
      await refreshExpiredToken();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Retrieve the existing token from cookies on page load
    const { token } = getAuthTokens();
    setAccessToken(token);
    checkForImpersonationToken().finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (accessToken) {
      setLoading(true); // Start loading when accessToken is present
      fetchUser()
        .then(u => {
          setUser(u);
        })
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }
  }, [accessToken]);

  const login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    setLoading(true); // Start loading when logging in
    try {
      const credentials: any = { username, password };
      const response = await coreApi.Tokens.create(credentials);
      const { token, refreshToken, expiresAt } = response;

      // Set token in cookies
      setAuthTokensInCookies({ token, refreshToken, expiresAt });
      setAccessToken(token);
    } catch (error) {
      setAccessToken(null);
      setLoading(false); // Stop loading if login fails
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const fetchUser = async () => {
    if (accessToken) {
      return coreApi.Users.setAuthToken(accessToken).get('me');
    }
    return null;
  };

  const refreshExpiredToken = async () => {
    const { refreshToken, expiresAt } = getAuthTokens();
    if (refreshToken && expiresAt && new Date(expiresAt) > new Date()) {
      const refreshTokenResponse = await coreApi.RefreshTokens.post({
        refreshToken,
      });
      if (refreshTokenResponse) {
        setAuthTokensInCookies(refreshTokenResponse);
        setAccessToken(refreshTokenResponse.token);
      }
    } else {
      const { token } = getAuthTokens();
      setAccessToken(token);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    clearAuthTokens();
    setAccessToken(null);
    setUser(null);
    window.location.replace('/signIn');
  };

  const isPermissionPresent = (permission: Permissions) => {
    return user?.permissions?.includes(permission) ?? false;
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingSpinner isCentered defaultSpinner size="size-oht-1400" />;
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        accessToken,
        login,
        logout,
        isPermissionPresent,
        refreshExpiredToken,
        checkForImpersonationToken,
        fetchUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;


I have this authContext on my app and I can't seem to identify why when I refresh the page I'm getting 3 console.logs of the user 2 with null value and one with the final value of the user and I use the user on another WhiteLabelContext to load partner assets and designTokens. Local it seems to work just fine when I login and when I refresh the page but on stagging the login works but the refresh of the page is showing the children without the partnerAssets and DesignTokens for a moment and then switch I think is because somehow when I refresh the user is being sent null for the WhiteLabelContext
What am I not seeing here?
